# Pandas Dataframe Iterating

Tags: python, pandas

long time listener first time caller. I'm using Python 2.7 on OS 10.9.

I have two .csv files: one a list of interesting genes and one a master list of ~17,000 genes with 4 associated columns of metrics (floats).  I created a master dataframe (keys are gene names) using pandas and passed it a list of my interesting genes using .loc.  My new_df is a resulting data frame from that iterative process. Admittedly, there is probably a more idiomatic way of doing this (i.e merging a pandas series with dataframe).

Using new_df I would like resample the master_df searching for and binning genes that are similar.  I'm looking for genes whose values are within 5% of my interesting gene's values in each the four columns.  When I find a match, it gets binned under the correct key in my new_df.  Is there a pandas way to accomplish this with hierarchical indexing?  Or perhaps this a task for a new dictionary? 
Thanks for your guidance!

Here is a snippet of code:

```
import pandas as pd

def list_getter():
    gene_list = []
    with open('experiment.csv', 'U') as f:
        for i in f:
            gene_list.append(i)
        gene_list[:] = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in gene_list]
        return gene_list
        f.close()

def master_df():
    master_df = pd.read_csv('Gene_Metrics_to_Consider.csv', index_col=0) #index by gene name

def gene_find(gene_list, df2):
    '''takes list of genes, returns new dataframe with extracted metrics'''
    for i in gene_list: #find genes and associated metrics
        new_df = df2.loc[gene_list] #NaN returned for genes not found
    return new_df

def bin_similar_genes():
```

Comment: With some code extract of what you have done so far it would help to guide you... Also consider using some accessible data on the Web so we can help you improve your code.

Comment: Please consider producing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get better/faster answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?  If so, I can provide a more detailed explanation in an edit.  If not, please clarify with sample data and desired results.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

gene_master = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), index=list('ABCDE'))

>>> gene_master
          0         1         2         3
A  0.156349  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327
B -0.302303 -1.048553 -1.420018 -1.706270
C  1.950775 -0.509652 -0.438074 -1.252795
D  0.777490 -1.613898 -0.212740 -0.895467
E  0.386902 -0.510805 -1.180632 -0.028182
```

Let's create a list of genes where the first two are close matches and the other three are not.

```
np.random.seed(0)
genes.iloc[:2] *= (1 + np.random.random([2, 4]) / 100)
genes.iloc[2:] *= (1 + np.random.random([3, 4]))
```

I'll change the index to some random identifiers:

```
genes.index = list('uvwxyz')
>>> genes
           0          1         2         3
v   0.158937   1.256877  1.224254 -0.393693
w  -0.306161  -1.069002 -1.438741 -1.752327
x  14.770935  -1.349448 -2.519776 -4.477268
y   2.997576 -11.523171 -0.261374 -1.150517
z   0.410848  -3.143927 -6.637809 -0.184293
```

With a given tolerance (e.g. 5%), I presume there can be multiple genes that are similar.  I use a dictionary comprehension to iterate through each gene which is compared against the master database (I divide the latter by the former).  I then look for rows where the difference in all four columns is less than 5%.

```
tolerance = 0.05
matches = {gene_id: gene_master[(gene_master.div(genes.ix[gene_id].values) - 1)
                    .abs()
                    .lt(tolerance)
                    .gt(0)  # prevents inclusion of identical gene.
                    .all(axis=1)].index.tolist()
           for gene_id in genes.index}
```

Now just remove any empty results where no match is found:

```
matches = {gene_id: vals for gene_id, vals in matches.iteritems() if len(vals) > 0}
>>> matches
{'v': ['A'], 'w': ['B']}
```

Now we can convert this back to a DataFrame:

```
idx1 = []
idx2 = []
_ = [idx1.extend([gene_id] * len(gene_ids)) for gene_id, gene_ids in matches.iteritems()]
_ = [idx2.extend(gene_ids) for gene_ids in matches.itervalues()]
matches_df = pd.DataFrame({'gene_id': idx1, 'master_gene_id': idx2})
matches_df['gene_id'] = idx1
matches_df['master_gene_id'] = idx2
matches_df.set_index('gene_id', inplace=True)
>>> matches_df
        master_gene_id
gene_id               
w                    B
v                    A
```

Also, using the `with open() as f:` structure, you don't need the `f.close()` statement.  It will close itself when the block terminates.

Comment: Very helpful for the first portion of my code (i.e passing in a list and outputting desired.  Thanks, I will re-tweak that.

Comment: The overarching problem is this: taking my new_df and searching thru the master_df for genes that may be "twins".  That is to say, their 4 values are very similar (each being within about 5% of one of my genes of interest listed in the experiment.csv).

Comment: so your list of genes also has 4 columns, and you are trying to find the closest match?

Comment: Alexander, this was extraordinarily helpful!  It may take me some time to evaluate and apply.  I will report back.  I am proactively calling this question answered.  Please let me know if there are other methods for up voting and giving positive feedback!

Comment: I need some additional help with this piece of code:  The dictionary comprehension works as expected, however it also (correctly) identifies itself from the master list.  That is to say, each member of my gene_list identifies itself in the master metrics list (because it obviously meets the tolerance threshold).  Where is the best place to put an if statement, or similar, that allows me to ignore and not bin the identical key from the master_df?  Thanks in advance.  This feels like a simple question, but I'm not creating the proper syntax within the dict comprehension.

Comment: See my .gt(0) edit above which means the difference has to be greater than zero to prevent inclusion of identical genes.

Comment: That's a much simpler solution to the problem than my if/while frustrations...  Thanks again.

Comment: I"m certainly confused about the performance of the .lt and .gt operators.  The .lt operator in within the dict comprehension performs as expected, however, the .gt operator will not.  If I comment out the .lt, the .gt works as implemented and vice versa.  What is the issue here?  I just switched to a new machine running OS X 10.10 still using 2.7.  What gives?  Again, individually both operators work fine.

Comment: perhaps a floating point issue?  Try `.gt(0.000001)` to see if that works.

Comment: There may be something else at play here.  I'm not sure the .gt is the issue. Removing both of these operators yields every key in the gene_master file (as expected) except the matching value.  I'm thoroughly confused now and will keep futzing with it.